# How to autolayout buttons in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm new to Swift and iOS Programming.

Actually working on an ios calculator-like project in order to practice.

as shown in my screenshot, I can auto layout four buttons in a row, but I'm stuck to auto layout the 3 buttons at the bottom. how can I solve this issue please ? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Do you can provide your design, which you want to achieve.

Comment: use UIStackview in IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special , you can do

[image]

like

```
mainStack - vertical - 5 subs
  subStack1 - horizontal - 4 buttons
  subStack2 - horizontal - 4 buttons
  subStack3 - horizontal - 4 buttons
  subStack4 - horizontal - 4 buttons
  subStack5 - horizontal - 3 buttons
```

distribution is `fillEqually` for all , `mainStack` constraints

> top (say 200) , bottom , leading and trailing to superView

Answer (score 1):

Do you use stack views to do the layout? I'd probably advise you to put these two buttons inside a horizontal stack view and then align it's trailing constraint to a trailing constraint of a button 3. But there might be other options depending on what you are trying to achieve  :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like problem with `UIStackView` filling. You probably set *Distribution* as `Fill equally` which doesn't work in this case where you need ratio of you buttons in this proportion:

`1 : 1 : 2`

This can be solved by setting *Distribution* of your stack view as `Fill Proportionally`

[image]

then just set equal widths for 1st and 2nd item. And for 2nd and 3st.

[image]

Then click on constraint for width relation between 2nd and 3st buttons' width and set multiplier to `1:2`

[image]

---

[image]